# getaddrinfo returns always 11001 (host not found)

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, platform

Although the searched FQDN appears in etc\hosts file.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you really on windows? Because that haven't the hosts file in etc/hosts, but somewhere in WINDOWS, or system32...

Comment: %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, if you're looking for it.

Comment: Actual arguments to the call, and the relevant line(s) from etc\hosts would be useful.

Comment: The line is the hosts file (yes, %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) is OK. Another reason?

Comment: This could also be an indication of a non-programming error, e.g. as described in http://superuser.com/questions/86751/ . Does ping work for the same (_literally_ the same) address?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have code, here's a guess:

```
getaddrinfo("http://www.example.com");
```

Doesn't work; getaddrinfo takes a hostname not a URL.